# undefined method `save' for nil:NilClass on controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am begging to learn ruby on rails and doing the following I am receiving the following errors:

> NoMethodError in ArticlesController#create
>
> undefined method `save' for nil:NilClass

**It has to do with the @article.save**

**articles_controllers.rb**

```
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController
 def new
   @article = Article.new
 end
 def create
 #render plain: params[:article].inspect
   @article = Article.new(article_params)
   @article.save
   redirect_to articles_show(@article)
 end
 private
   def article_params
   params.require(:article).permit(:tittle, :description)  
   end
 end
```

**routes.rb**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

root 'pages#home'

get 'about', to: 'pages#about'

resources :articles

end
```

**new.html.erb**

## Create an article

```
<%= form_for @article do |f| %>

<p>
    <%= f.label :tittle %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :tittle %>
</p>
<p>
    <%= f.label :description %> <br>
    <%= f.text_area :description %>
</p>
<p>
    <%= f.submit %> 
</p>

<% end %>
```

Answer (score 4):

```
undefined method `save' for nil:NilClass
```

This error means you are calling the `save` method on a NilClass object i.e. `nil`.

When you do this: `@article.save`, for some reason, `@article` is `nil` here and hence you get that error. Make sure you populate the `@article` object and then call: `@article.save`.

Check your Rails log and put some debugging prints like: `puts @article.inspect` before you try to save it or so.

Answer (score 3):

The error is here:

```
def create
   @article = Article.new article_params
   @article.save # <- Error
   redirect_to articles_show(@article)
end
```

**The error is caused by `@article` not being present** when you call `.save` on it.

---

Your code looks good.

The error *must* be caused by some other part of your app - I'm thinking your model.

I would ensure you have the following:

```
#app/models/article.rb
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
   #-> also make sure you have the appropriate datatable
end
```

This should allow you to invoke the `.new` method on the class, which will then allow you to call `.save` as well.

The error you have is likely either because you don't have your model (which is unlikely because Rails would have failed with an "unrecognized constant" error), or your datatable doesn't exist.